# Git Rebase or Git Merge?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

I have two branches. Both are feature branches - `new-ui` and `video-upload`. `video-upload` is a fork of `new-ui`.

However, `video-upload` has a TON of commits. I have multiple developers working on `new-ui`, and one just completed `video-upload`. But I can't quite figure out which will be the cleaner option to combine the two.

I want to bring the completed work in `video-upload` into `new-ui`, but I don't know if I want to completely erase all the commits for `video-upload` and create a new commit history for `new-ui` with new commits. That feels like it will be messy.

But at the same time, I want a clean merge of the functionality.

Work has been done on `new-ui` since `video-upload` has been forked. So the merge/combination is not going to be clean.

Considering the above, which approach is best and why?

Comment: Just merge video-upload into new-ui? That’s what merging is for. If the rebase won’t be clean, it’s not worth it to rebase.

Comment: Is that cleaner than a rebase @minitech?

Comment: It’s clean. Whether it’s cleaner than a rebase is up to your tastes. Of course, if you can’t manage to do the rebase, it doesn’t really matter which is cleaner, does it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Merge is exactly for that - shipping a version that includes development from two or more branches.

Rebase is for "rewriting history": to have a consolidated main trunk that includes commits from several branches but looks like a monotonic stream.

Comment: So what do I do? Checkout the `new-ui` branch, and then do `git merge `video-upload`?

Comment: Yes, I'd checkout new-ui, create another branch (e.g. "ui-video-mix") that will contain the result of the merge, and then merge.