# How do I revert a git merge that had many commits

Tags: git, git-merge, revert

I have two branches `new-ui` and `video-upload` and I am trying to merge them. Before merging them though, I should have created a new branch that holds the result of both....to make sure that the merge result is what I am looking for. I didn't, so I would like to reverse the entire merge (ideally without having to go back through the logs and do it manually).

Both branches, post the fork, have had changes/commits applied to them. So, as you can imagine, the history of both is quite messy.

I want to just revert `new-ui` to the state it was at before I just merged `video-upload` to it. Then I can go ahead and create a new branch then do the merge there.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Give me a history - did you merge `new-ui` and `video-upload` into master?  Was it just a straight merge between those two specific branches?  And you don't want anything that was on `video-upload` in that branch until you can fix things?

Comment: @Makoto So it started with this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32362647/git-rebase-or-git-merge. TL;DR: I have two feature branches, one was forked from the other and work was done on the 2nd as well as the first (after the 2nd was forked). I am trying to merge the changes done on the second back into the first. I went ahead and did that, but now regret it - so I want to revert the merge. How do I revert that merge?

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6217372/1079354) out.  It feels like this could be a duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undo a Git merge?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389361/undo-a-git-merge)

Comment: How do I know what the correct `commit_hash` is for the merge?

Comment: You'll have a merge commit in your history. Look through `git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all` to see if you can spot it.

Comment: @Makoto So I see multiple lines like this: `| | * | |   e28e932 Merge branch 'new-ui' of github.com:me/myapp into video-upload`. Do I look for the outermost/latest one? I am trying to make sense of this all and make sure I choose the right commit. Can you give me some indication of what I should be looking for, because I am just seeing a bunch of the commits of both branches jumped into one.

Comment: @Makoto The differences with all the lines is that the graphic depiction of the branches looks different. So the commit I pasted above, is furthest back in my commit log history (and therefore has more graphics in the illustration). Here is the 2nd furthest back commit `| | * |   490f276 Merge branch 'new-ui' of github.com:me/myapp into video-upload`. Notice that the graphic looks less, i.e. only 1 `|` after the `*` as opposed to `| |` in the one above.

Comment: Paste the result of that log in your question. We can pinpoint when it was merged in that way.

Answer (score -2):

Git has two helpful properties here: Your merge commit links to both of its parents (`new-ui` and `video-upload` both before the merge), and even if it didn't, git is very conservative about deleting history. If all you're trying to do is to undo the merge, you have a few options to find the commit you're looking for:

- `git log new-ui` to see the combined history of `new-ui`
- `git reflog` to see the history of what you've checked out, particularly handy if no name or branch points to it

And then a couple of options to make `new-ui` point to it again:

- `git checkout YOUR_COMMIT_HASH -B new-ui`, which will *make new-ui point to YOUR_COMMIT_HASH intead of whatever it was pointing to before*
- `git reset --hard YOUR_COMMIT_HASH`, if you already have `new-ui` checked out, which will *get rid of any local changes, check out YOUR_COMMIT_HASH, and point the current branch (new-ui) at it*

Comment: Why all the downvotes? This seems like a reasonable solution...but I can't understand why they are down voting.

Comment: @marcamillion Beats me! If there are any obvious mistakes, I'd be happy to be corrected, or have my answer copy/paste/modified into something better. Hope _you_ find the answer useful, in any case! :)